# (rosjava) class files of custom messages cannot be found

Tags: rosjava, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm making a custom stack using rosjava. After writing some code, rosmake successfully ends but I can't find the message class that I made.

[This page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava/Build) says as quoted below. If so, where can I put .msg files, and where the .class files of those messages are generated in?

```
you cannot place msg or srv files in a rosjava-based package. They have to be in a separate package. This is not considered a major issue as this is generally best practice anyway.
```

.msg file I made (it is placed under `%STACK_HOME%/msg` currently though I know this doesn't work. Just had no idea where to put it.):

```
uint32 clockValue
geometry_msgs/Point[] points
```

.jar files of geometry_msgs and other messages provided by ROS are already generated under .ros/rosjava/lib as expected.

I need to know this because I can't use the custom message unless I know the class name and (Java's) package name of the .class file of the message. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11602/(rosjava)-class-files-of-custom-messages-cannot-be-found/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the message is telling you to create another (non-java) package within your stack that contains only the message definitions.

Have you tried that?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-10-26**:
@joq oh that sounds like a good/best practice that I haven't found so far anywhere in ROS related documents!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-10-24**:
Good. Keeping all the messages in a separate package is a good idea, anyway. It minimizes dependencies between the other packages.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-10-24**:
I tried referring to .msg in the existing .cpp package based on your hint (because I already tried similar stuff in .cpp so that I defined .msg in that package), and it worked. @joq 's suggestion should also work if you haven't made .msg definition. Thank you!

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-10-20**:
@joq thank you, I've never thought about it (nor seen the direction like that). I'll try see how it works.